# It is wrong to extend a singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

Singleton's concept (at least in java) says that it must be implemented with a private constructor, right?
Ex:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton uniqueInstance;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null)
            uniqueInstance = new Singleton();

        return uniqueInstance;
    }
```

However, if we ignore this fact and do it with a protected constructor, would he stop being a singleton? I saw some examples on the internet with this scenario.

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton singleton;

    protected Singleton() {
    }

    public synchronized static Singleton getInstance() {

    if (singleton == null) {

        int tipoDoSingletonParaInstanciar = leUmArquivoTexto();

        if (tipoDoSingletonParaInstanciar == 1) {
        singleton = new SingletonSubclasse1();
        } else if(tipoDoSingletonParaInstanciar == 2) {
        singleton = new SingletonSubclasse2();
        } else {
        singleton = new Singleton();
        }
    }

    return singleton;
    }

    public void metodoQuePodeSerSobrescrito() {
    System.err.println("Singleton.metodoQuePodeSerSobrescrito()");
    }
}
```

And if the protected constructor is not a problem in itself ... inheriting a singleton  not mean that its subclasses could create several instances of the parent? Doesn't it break the concept?

Is it possible to inherit a Singleton without breaking its concepts (blocking)?

Comment: `Singleton` should be `final`. If you create a subclass of `Singleton`, it **is-a** `Singleton`. So you have two. And that is **not** a `Singleton`.

Comment: There's an important difference between a singleton and an object that you intentionally only create one instance of. You're describing the latter.

Answer (score 2):

There by you create more than one object, which means its not singleton anymore .
And if you do so you are breaking the concept of singleton.

You should use protected constructor When a class is  an abstract class. In that situation you don't want objects to be instantiated from the class but only use it to inherit from.

Comment: In the case of the protected builder you say?

Comment: When having protected constructor in singleton